# Is every bijective analytic map bi-analytic?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Suppose that

- $E$ and $F$ are complex Banach spaces and $U\subset E$ and $V\subset F$ are open subses.
- $f\colon U\to V$ is analytic
- $f\colon U\to V$ is bijective

Is $f$ bi-analytic? (i.e. is its inverse $f^{-1}\colon V\to U$ analytic?)

I heard this result is known but I could not find a reference

EDIT: As pointed out by @abx my original question in the real analytic setting has trivial counter examples.

Comment: What about $E=F=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x^3$?

Comment: For a proof of the inverse function theorem in this setting see Adrien Douady's thesis in Annales Institut Fourier vol 16 1966 page 13 .As abx has pointed you need the differential of the map to be an isomorphism at every point .

Comment: @abx of course. One should in addition ask $f$ to be locally bijective on $U$.

Comment: thank you. I am well aware of the inverse function theorem. In fact as @abx pointed out I should rephrase the question as follows: if $f\colon U\to V$ is analytic an bijective, is it also bi-analytic.

Comment: Theorem 15.1.8 on page 302 in Rudin's Function Theory in the Unit Ball of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (1980 edition) provides an affirmative answer to your question when $E=F=\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @T.Le Thank you for the reference! In fact, in infinite dimensions it is particularly the ontoness of the differential which I am interested in.